# Auxílio com desempenho de update

Tags: firebird, delphi-7

Estou com a seguinte situação: tenho que atualizar alguns ids com o `where` em um número de requisição, mas são entre dois bancos, firebirds, diferentes. Fiz isso:

```
while not qry1.eof do
begin
  Qry2.sql.text := ' update tabela set id = 
  qry1.fieldbyname('id').asstring where numero = 
  qry1.fieldbyname('numero').asstring ' ;

  Qry2.execsql;

  Qry1.next;
End;
```

Isso dá certo (escrevi um pouco diferente aqui pra não escrever muito). Mas dessa forma demora  mais do que eu gostaria.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como melhorar isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma lista de updates e execute-as de uma só vez, algo como:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE tabela WHERE ID = X;
  UPDATE tabela WHERE ID = X;
  UPDATE tabela WHERE ID = X;
  ...
END;
```

Muito fácil e rápido. Pode utilizar o mesmo laço que esta fazendo, porém, ao invés de adicionar na query e executar, adiciona em uma lista e depois executa o bloco inteiro.

Comment: Obrigado. Ficou bem mais rápido.